# find out index of several using directive / angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i wrote a directive that give out some clickable divs for a kicker game, it look like that:

```
<span>Team 1</span>
<scoreDisplay>
    <div ng-click="setScore(0)" class="score-item">1</div>
    <div ng-click="setScore(1)" class="score-item">2</div>
    <div ng-click="setScore(2)" class="score-item">3</div>
    <div ng-click="setScore(3)" class="score-item">4</div>
    <div ng-click="setScore(4)" class="score-item">5</div>
    <div ng-click="setScore(5)" class="score-item">6</div>
</scoreDisplay>

<span>Team 2</span>
<scoreDisplay>
    <div ng-click="setScore(0)" class="score-item">1</div>
    <div ng-click="setScore(1)" class="score-item">2</div>
    <div ng-click="setScore(2)" class="score-item">3</div>
    <div ng-click="setScore(3)" class="score-item">4</div>
    <div ng-click="setScore(4)" class="score-item">5</div>
    <div ng-click="setScore(5)" class="score-item">6</div>
</scoreDisplay>
```

after a click on a score-item, i want to get the index of the directive, 
where the items inside, here the scopefunction inside  the controller:

```
$scope.game = {
    team_1:{name:'Ateam',score:0}
    team_2:{name:'Bteam',score:0}
};
$scope.setScore = function(itemindex, directiveindex){
    $scope.game["team_"+(directiveindex+1)].score = (itemindex+1)

}
```

any idea, how i can get the directive-index (the parent elemment dom index) with angular?
thanks for helping.

Comment: Use '$index' for this purpose and 'ng-repeat' directive.

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-repeat directive for code parts like:

```
    <div ng-click="setScore(0)" class="score-item">1</div>
    <div ng-click="setScore(1)" class="score-item">2</div>
    <div ng-click="setScore(2)" class="score-item">3</div>
    <div ng-click="setScore(3)" class="score-item">4</div>
    <div ng-click="setScore(4)" class="score-item">5</div>
    <div ng-click="setScore(5)" class="score-item">6</div>
```

You can replace in controller:

```
$scpe.teams = [...]
```

In template:

```
<div ng-repeat="team in teams" ng-click="setScore(team.score,$index)" class="score-item">{{team.name}}</div>
```

You can make similar change for scoreDisplay

Comment: I m using ng-repeat in the directive and i don't want the index of the directive items, i want to found out the directive - index like this:
    <mydirective index="1"></mydirective>
    <mydirective index="2"></mydirective>

Comment: Not sure I understood your comment...  If you want to get directive scope, then angular.element('...').scope() if you want parent index then you need use jquery

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution with a attribute "index":

```
<scoreDisplay index="1"></scoreDisplay>
<scoreDisplay index="2"></scoreDisplay>
```

This works fine, but i will search for a better solution 
like this or with something like:

```
angular.element("body scoreDisplay").index($event.target);
```